# R Shiny: Content of tabItem not showing when there are menuSubItems

Tags: r, shiny

Consider the following R Shiny code:

```
# ui.R

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("First", tabName="First"),
      menuItem("Transportation", tabName = "Transportation",  
                         menuSubItem("Air", tabName = "Air"),
                         menuSubItem("Maritime", tabName = "Maritime")))),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "First",
                                 headerPanel('First')),
                         tabItem(tabName = "Transportation",
                                 headerPanel('Transportation')),
                         tabItem(tabName = "Air",
                                 headerPanel('Air')),
                         tabItem(tabName = "Maritime",
                                 headerPanel('Maritime')))))
```

When I click on the *Transportation* menu item, why do I not see the `headerPanel('Transportation')`?

Is this the expected behavior?  Is the expected behavior that content in a tabItem should be ignored in the case where the corresponding menuItem has menuSubItems?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for, but this makes a Transportation `headerPanel` show:

```
menuItem("Transportation", tabName = "Transportation",  
               menuSubItem("Air", tabName = "Air"),
               menuSubItem("Maritime", tabName = "Maritime"),
               menuSubItem("Transportation", tabName = "Transportation")))),
```

Comment: No, that's not what I'm looking for.  If this is the expected behavior, that's fine; I just want to know that it's the expected behavior.

Comment: Hm. I'm not familiar enough with `shinydashboard` to know if that's what should be expected